# Is there an easy way to declare an array of objects and not have to initialize all of them?

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I need to be able to create a 2d array of linked-lists, with the dimensions spanning the alphabet. The goal is to have each row be aligned with the first letter of a word and each column be aligned with the second letter. The issue is that I only have 200 words I need to add in, so at least 476+ slots won't be used if I had to initialize every linked-list object.

Comment: This is a case where an image could be very helpful to assist in visualizing the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why do you need linked lists if you know how many elements there are? Do you really want to put linked lists in an "array", or are you actually describing some kind of graph structure that represents a *sparse* 2d array? Are you worried about space? If so, then a) why is it a problem to have a whole 676 elements allocated; and b) why do you expect the savings from not having 476 of those elements, to outweigh the overhead of creating the links?

Comment: It's not so clear what you're asking.  I don't know what "dimensions spanning the alphabet" means.  Does it mean you want a 2D array with 26x26 elements?  You know that any memory can be initalized to zero with `memset`, and you can use `nullptr` as a value for a pointer that doesn't have anything to point to, right?

Comment: Not only is it not clear why you need or want to do what you describe, nor is it quite exactly understood *what you are trying to do*, but I have absolutely no idea *what help you need*. Please read [ask] and try to create a more *specific* question. It definitely helps to show any code you've tried writing so far.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The program is supposed to take in a file containing 200 words as a dictionary. Then, the program is supposed to add those words into a hash table and be able to access them to return similar words. The linked lists are there to contain words with the same two first letters. Many of the spots aren't going to be used in the 2d array (26x26), so I'd rather not have them create over 500 objects that won't be used. The program has to automatically insert these words too, so I can't just pick and choose the spot count based on how many will actually be used.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I also need to make sure the program is roughly efficient. This is for a class assignment, so I can't really change much about how I'm going about it. I really just want to only allocate the spots that will have words in them and also have a way to check if the spot in the array is empty.

Comment: Ah, so you want some kind of 2-dimensional *hash table*. Did you consider just hashing the values based on their first two letters? Since you are using C++, did you consider using the built-in standard library type `std::map` to *map from* the first two letters to the entire string (or list of strings, whatever)?

Comment: "I also need to make sure the program is roughly efficient" I guarantee you that, for the data size you describe, you would have to go out of your way to deliberately make something inefficient enough for anyone to notice. You're reading the words in *from a file*; that's already *vastly* slower than anything your program is likely to do.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That was kinda the idea, yeah. I wanted to hash the first letter for the row and the second for the column. I've also never looked into std::map, so I'm not sure. I'll be reading in a file with 200 words and I have to hash those. Then, the user can input a word and I have to return similar words. I also have to include the execution time

Comment: But if the question really is "how can I design this data structure?", then you will probably have better luck on https://cs.stackexchange.com or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ShaneButler "*This is for a class assignment*" - then it likely needs to be based on concepts you are learning in class. If you don't understand something, talk to your teacher first.